# ActionParameters name mismatch... works! Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action

I've written an ActionFilter, which loads data from the session and provides object required by the action:

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("ProCalc"))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Engine already set!");
    }

    // Note: engine is just a simple local variable here!
    Engine engine = SessionHandler.RestoreProCalc();
    filterContext.ActionParameters["ProCalc"] = engine;
}
```

Notice, that I return the instance of my object by the name "ProCalc".

The action looks like the following:

```
[RequiresProCalcFilter]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Eval(Engine engine)
{
    // code
}
```

Notice, that though the types of object in `ActionParameters` and actual parameter match, I've mismatched the names of parameters: filter stores object under the name `ProCalc`, but action expects the parameter `engine` to be set.

But, to my great surprise, this actually works! But how?

I tried to disassembly my way through System.Web.Mvc assembly and ended up in `ActionDescriptor.ExtractParameterFromDictionary`. But this method throws an exception if parameter of given name is not found in dictionary, so this is a dead end. I couldn't also find any papers on the Internet on how `ActionParameters` names are bound to actual action parameters.

So which rules does apply here, such that mismatched names does not prevent action to be called properly?

Comment: When you say "it works," what do you mean exactly? `engine` is non-null within `Eval`?

Comment: It is not null and correctly loaded from the session, so it has to be the same instance.

Comment: Is it not matched based on types and not on parameters names?

Comment: If so, why the `Dictionary` instead of simple array or `IEnumerable`? What if there are several parameters of the same type? Can you possibly link to a site which defines how the ActionParameters actually work?